# Video format or MIME type is not supported. IIS does have the right MIME type.

Tags: iis, mime-types, mp4

This is driving me crazy. When I try to view the video embedded into the page, I get the following error in firefox "Video format or MIME type is not supported".

I am on IIS, and I do have the correct MIME type for MP4. Is there anything else I could check?

Comment: Did you get solution? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue ended up coming from our CMS.

The MP4 file was being loaded though a script, and that script's name contained "-", which the CMS decided to replace with ".". Simply opening up Firebug's Net tab allowed me to fix the error in a matter of minutes.

Firefox does not support H264 anyway, so that MP4 file had to be loaded through Flash.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with Firefox because I only had an mp4 file, but this javascript seems to work ok.

The new video tag is used and the object code is provided as a fallback. When Firefox can't find the non existent ogv file it throws an error, which runs the javascript to remove the video tag and just leave the fall back object code, which runs fine in Firefox. (I'm using JQuery, but the same could presumably be achieved with plain javascript.)

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
  function kill_video_tag() {
    // Remove source tags
    $('#vidid').children('source').remove();

    // Grab everything else inside
    var ob = $('#vidid').html();

    // Add the fallback code before the video tag
    // and then remove the video tag
    $('#vidid').before(ob).remove();
  }
</script>

<video id="vidid" width="320" height="256" controls>
  <source src="http://www.mysite.com/nice_video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="http://www.mysite.com/this_does_not_exist.ogv" type="video/ogg" onerror="kill_video_tag();" />
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="256" >
  <PARAM NAME="src" VALUE="http://www.mysite.com/nice_video.mp4" >
  <PARAM NAME="autoplay" VALUE="false" >
  <EMBED SRC="http://www.mysite.com/nice_video.mp4" TYPE="image/x-macpaint" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="256" AUTOPLAY="false"></EMBED>
</OBJECT>
</video>
```